# how can I get the operator type and apply formula into pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a python string like this: `str1='PRODUCT1_PRD/2+PRODUCT2_NON-PROD-PRODUCT3_NON-PRD/2'`
Here I want to get operator in a dynamic way and based on the operator I want to perform certain operation.I have a pandas dataframe df like this:

```
PRODUCT   PRD  NON-PORD
PRODUCT1  3      5
PRODUCT2  4      6
PRODUCT3  5      8
```

Output I want  a variable `var1=(3/2)+6-(8/2)=3.5` after applying the above formula. How can I do this most efficient way?

Want to note one thing: I have multiple formulas like what I mentioned, all are inside a list of strings. So I have to apply all those formulas one by one.

Comment: is the column name NON-PROD. Can this be changed to NONPROD. The - in NON-PROD conflicts with minus (-) sign for subtraction. Also, you may need to edit the example with NON-PROD instead of NON-PORD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create `MultiIndex Series` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and join index values by `_` in `map`:

```
s = df.set_index('PRODUCT').stack()
s.index = s.index.map('_'.join)
print (s)
PRODUCT1_PRD         3
PRODUCT1_NON-PROD    5
PRODUCT2_PRD         4
PRODUCT2_NON-PROD    6
PRODUCT3_PRD         5
PRODUCT3_NON-PROD    8
dtype: int64
```

Then replace values in string by `Series` and call [`pandas.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html):

```
str1='PRODUCT1_PRD/2+PRODUCT2_NON-PROD-PRODUCT3_NON-PROD/2'

for k, v in s.items():
    str1 = str1.replace(k, str(v))
print (str1)
3/2+6-8/2

print (pd.eval(str1))
3.5
```